# Can't redirect stdout and stderr in background

Tags: output, logs, task-management, background-process

I want to launch a task in background and redirect all outputs to a file.
For this, I do `./main.py > /tmp/logsFile 2>&1 &` but i doesn't work
I think the problem comes from the background task, when I do this but not in background, it works !
The problem when it's in background is that the file is created but empty and my bot always return things at the connection so the file should not be empty !
I have a MSI CX62 6QD 249XFR with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on i3

EDIT: The command above works with a basic .sh with echo but no with main.py

Comment: It may be due to output buffering. Try some solutions here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Comment: It work, thank you
How do I mark this post resolved ?

Comment: If it works, then please describe how you solved it in an answer to your question. That closes the question and leaves a reference for future users. It is perfectly fine here to answer your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by add the -u argument to the command who launches my python script.
The command is now `python3 -u main.py > /tmp/thebotlogs 2>&1 &`
Apparently, it's the output buffering so the -u argument disable it
Thank you for your answers :)